# Attempting to return inputs in Laravel 5.5 after failed validation

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am having a hard time finding documentation on how to return inputs when my validation fails in Laravel 5.5 using my code. Can anyone tell me how to return the inputs after the validation fails? Validation definitely is working. Is it possible to return the inputs with this validation method, or should I try another way? Here is my controller:

```
public function submit()
{

        $this->validate(request(),[

            'first' => 'required|alpha',
            'last' => 'required|alpha',
            'credentials' => 'required|alpha',
            'specialty'=>'required|alpha',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'pi' => 'required|alpha',
            'address1' => 'required|alpha',
            'address2' => 'required|alpha',
            'city' => 'required|alpha',
            'state'=>'required|alpha',
            'zip' => 'required|numeric',
            'phone' => 'required|alpha'

        ]);

        $data = request()->all();

        return view('hcp.forms.form-complete')->with('data', $data);
}
```

Comment: What you mean by _return the inputs_ ??!

Comment: He wants to have old values from submit (to use `{{ old('phone' }}`)

Answer (score 3):

use [`withInput()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#old-input)

```
return view('hcp.forms.form-complete')->with('data', $data)->withInput();
```

And display your old input for `username` as `old('username')` in your blade

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

Comment: Hey... I may be mistaken, but isn't all of the code after the validation array code that will only execute after the data has been validated? Thus, invalid data will not return?

Comment: Its good to display wrong data with error that. ie. `flfkf22@22` is invalid email you should display both wrong email and error. Also remove `->with('data', $data)` as you are sending all input with `withInput()`

Comment: You can exclude some data like `$request->except('password')` see the doc link

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the validate method on the request object? You only need to inject the Request object in your controller's method.

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'first' => 'required|alpha',
        'last' => 'required|alpha',
        'credentials' => 'required|alpha',
        'specialty'=>'required|alpha',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'pi' => 'required|alpha',
        'address1' => 'required|alpha',
        'address2' => 'required|alpha',
        'city' => 'required|alpha',
        'state'=>'required|alpha',
        'zip' => 'required|numeric',
        'phone' => 'required|alpha'
    ]);
```

If validation fails, this automatically redirects to previous request with old data available.

Comment: Once you use the request object as shown here, you can get access to the old input by using {{ old('phone') }} in your blade template. You can even have a default value like this {{ old('phone', 'Default') }}