# Laravel redirect back on submit

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have paginated model in the front-end which has standard CRUD options available. I would like to redirect back to the page I was before I edited or deleted my model.

That means if I was deleting the model on 3rd page, I would like to be redirected to 3rd page, not to original landing page, so naturally I did

```
return redirect()->back()
```

the issue with this approach is on the edit when the validation fails. Once validation fails I get redirected to the same edit page, thus effectively making that page the one that `back()` leads to.

Is there some simple solution to this without having to use sessions for remembering where I was on the time of editing and such?

**EDIT: example**

I am coming from `/customers` link

If I edit the customer I will get redirected to `/customers?page=5` if there are no errors.

If validation fails, I get redirected back to editing page to fix my errors.

Now when I fix errors so that validation passes, on submit I will get redirected to `/customer/{id}/edit` instead of `/customers?page=5`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `withInput()` to get back old input values in `old` function

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

Read about [old input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#old-input)

Also check [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46853529/2815635)

Comment: You didn't get my question. Old input is not the issue, it is the `back()` link